# Generic xpath for a node at different locations

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a lot of xml files from different versions of schemas. There are certain sections/tags in these xmls that are the same.
What I want to do is locate a perticular tag and start processing that tag. The thing is that this tag may appear at different locations in the xml.
So I am looking for a xpath that will locate this node irrespective of its location. I am using Java for writing my processing code.
Following are the various falvours of the xmls
Sample 1

```
<nodeIWant>
       <book>
          <title>Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</title>
          ...
       </book>
</nodeIWant>
```

Sample 2

```
<a>
   <nodeIWant>
      <book>
         <title>Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</title>
         ...
      </book>
   </nodeIWant>
</a>
```

Sample 3

```
<b>
   <nodeIWant>
      <book>
         <title>Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</title>
         ...
      </book>
   </nodeIWant>
</b>
```

In the above xmls I want to use the same xpath to locate the node '*nodeIWant*'.

The Java code I am using is the following

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document modelDoc = docBuilder.parse(args[0]);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
System.out.println(xPath.evaluate("//nodeIWant", modelDoc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE));
```

This prints out a null.

**Final Edit**
The answer by Mathias Müller works for these xml files. I am actually trying to query the .emx files in Rational Software Architect. I was trying to avaoid using these for examples. (Please don't start talking about BIRT and using the eclipse uml APIs etc... I have tried these and they do not give me what I want.)
The structure of the files is the following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--xtools2_universal_type_manager-->
<?com.ibm.xtools.emf.core.signature <signature id="com.ibm.xtools.uml.msl.model" version="7.0.0"><feature description="" name="com.ibm.xtools.ruml.feature" url="" version="7.0.0"/></signature>?>
<?com.ibm.xtools.emf.core.signature <signature id="com.ibm.xtools.mmi.ui.signatures.diagram" version="7.0.0"><feature description="" name="Rational Modeling Platform (com.ibm.xtools.rmp)" url="" version="7.0.0"/></signature>?>
<xmi:XMI version="2.0" xmlns:Default="http:///schemas/Default/_fNm3AAqoEd6-N_NOT9vsCA/2" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http:///schemas/Default/_fNm3AAqoEd6-N_NOT9vsCA/2 pathmap://UML2_MSL_PROFILES/Default.epx#_fNwoAAqoEd6-N_NOT9vsCA?Default/Default?">
  <uml:Model name="A" xmi:id="_4lzSsMywEeGAuoBpYhfj6Q">
  <!-- Lot of other stuff -->
  </uml:Model>
<xmi:XMI>
```

The other file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--xtools2_universal_type_manager-->
<?com.ibm.xtools.emf.core.signature <signature id="com.ibm.xtools.uml.msl.model" version="7.0.0"><feature description="" name="com.ibm.xtools.ruml.feature" url="" version="7.0.0"/></signature>?>
<?com.ibm.xtools.emf.core.signature <signature id="com.ibm.xtools.mmi.ui.signatures.diagram" version="7.0.0"><feature description="" name="Rational Modeling Platform (com.ibm.xtools.rmp)" url="" version="7.0.0"/></signature>?>
<uml:Model xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_4lzSsMywEeGAuoBpYhfj6Q" name="A">
<!-- Lot of other stuff -->
</uml:Model>
```

Shouldn't the xpath of '//Model' work for these two samples as well?

Comment: Sure that your input documents are well-formed XML?

Comment: Yes.wouldn't the parse method throw an exception if it weren't the case? Just wondering...

Comment: I am asking because it looks like `br` is not closed in your examples.

Comment: sorry, that was for a page break, until i figured out the <code> formating option. I have corrected this.

Comment: A common problem using XPath 1.0 and not getting a result is a default namespace on the selected elements. Are there namespaces declared in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very familiar with DocumentBuilder, but perhaps you need to compile an XPath expression before evaluating it against a document? It seems it's not XPath expressions that are evaluated, XML documents are.

```
String expression = "//nodeIWant";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(modelDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Or, if there is just one of those elements and you'd like to print its string value:

```
String expression = "//nodeIWant";
System.out.println(xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(modelDoc));
```

---

**EDIT**: You edited your question and revealed the *actual* XML you are evaluating path expressions against. Those new documents have *namespaces* that you need to take into account in XPath expressions.

`//nodeIWant` will never find a node if it is actually in a namespace. To find the `Model` node in your new documents, you'd have to use

```
//*[local-name() = 'Model']
```

Comment: I am not sure if calling compile makes any difference. you answer is correct, but please take look at my final edit of the question.

Comment: @Ajay For your future questions, please show the actual XML document _right away_ instead of showing a random, completely unrelated document. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xPath 'axis' `//`. This searches in the file for your node and doesn't care about the parent-nodes. So in your example you can use:

```
//nodeIWant
```

Comment: The XPath in this answer is correct, but `//` is not a wildcard. It is an **axis**, a shorthand for `descendant-or-self::`.

Comment: I have tried this but this returns a null. I have editted my question to add the Java code I am using.

Comment: @Ajay Where do we stand with this? Did you try what I have suggested, together with this Xpath expression from Christian?

Answer (score 0):

Since the example you provided contains more than just a `String` in the `<nodeIWant>` elements you probably can benefit from using an object oriented approach combined with xpath. With [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project) it's possible to do this:

```
public class DataProjection {

public interface Book {

    @XBRead("./title")
    String getTitle();

    //... more getter or setter methods
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print all books in all <nodeIWant> elements of 
    for (String file : new String[] { "a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml" }) {
        List<Book> books = new XBProjector().io().file(file).evalXPath("//nodeIWant/book").asListOf(Book.class);
        for (Book book : books) {
            System.out.println(book.getTitle());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You can define one or more views (called projection interfaces) to the XML data and use XPath to connect the data to java objects implementing these interfaces. This helps a lot in structuring your code and have it reuseable for similar XML files.